# TCPDF MultiCell Auto AddPage

Tags: php, tcpdf

Good Day Guys! I need some help when using TCPDF, I have this problem where the first page renders the details ok but on the second page, all the details are stacked at one area, I'm using MultiCell for the details.

```
public function PageHeader() {
        $this->SetMargins(5, $this->GetY(), -1, true);
        $this->SetCellPadding(0); 
}

private function _addPage() {
        $top_margin = 50;
        $this->AddPage();
        $this->setCellHeightRatio(1.25);
        $this->SetMargins(5, $top_margin, 5, true);
        $this->SetTopMargin($top_margin);
    }
```

Comment: Can you please post a minimal, fully working example? It's hard to reproduce your problem with the code you've posted.

Comment: If you want the best help from the other then you need to post minimal fully working example code like `lxg` said

Comment: Yep, Thanks for the inputs. The problem lies with the number of records on the details since I declared my page header and footer.